# Asynchronous Python - fire and forget HTTP request

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Not sure if that's achievable. I want to fire an HTTP POST request from a script, but not wait for a response. Instead I want to return immediately.

I tries something along these lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def fire():
    await client.post('http://httpresponder.com/xyz')

async def main():
    asyncio.ensure_future(fire())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    client = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The script returns immediately without errors, but the HTTP request never arrives at the destination. Can I fire the POST request, but not wait for response from the server, just terminate the moment the request is sent?

Comment: Have you tried to use the `requests` with the `stream` parameter ? This way it won't download the [body content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) (But still waits for the server to respond)

Comment: Check my answer bellow, I think it should be the accepted one ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/73967795/2992192

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [have answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526506/wait-for-db-future-to-complete/52540427#52540427) a rather similar question.

```
async def main():
    asyncio.ensure_future(fire())
```

`ensure_future` [schedules coro execution](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task), but does not wait for its completion and `run_until_complete` does not wait for the completion of all futures.

This should fix it:

```
async def main():
    await fire()
```

Comment: Hi this does the job. However, the script sends the request as expected and then terminates immediately with the message:
`Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7fa486dc6550>                                         
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fa481475828>, 20136.829498141)]']           
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7fa48527bdd8> ` The script's exit code is still `0` (no error)

Comment: Hi! You should use session `async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session: session.post(...)`. For details see [docs](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request)

Comment: the error is gone. However, I don't think that this set-up actually achieves what was the original intention (terminate script as soon as request is sent). Currently, the main script will be executing as long as the client session is open within the context guard (`aysnc ... with ... as ...`). The client session will be closed only when the response arrives (`await response`). I ended up using multiprocessing for what I needed. Of course asyncio and aiohttp are great for executing multiple network calls asynchronously, but they seem not capable of "firing and forgetting"

Answer (score 15):

Using `asyncio` you can write a simple decorator as `@background`. Now you can write whatever inside `foo()` and the control-flow will not wait for its completion.

```
import asyncio
import time


def background(f):
    from functools import wraps
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        if callable(f):
            return loop.run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise TypeError('Task must be a callable')    
    return wrapped


@background
def foo():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("foo() completed")


print("Hello")
foo()
print("I didn't wait for foo()")
```

Produces:

```
Hello
I didn't wait for foo()
foo() completed
```

Comment: **Note:** "*Deprecated since version 3.10:* Deprecation warning is emitted if there is no running event loop. In future Python releases, this function will be an alias of `get_running_loop()`." https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop

Comment: Is it possible to add some rate limiting mechanisms on top of this using the python `ratelimit` module?

Comment: @SudharshannD It should work along with other decorators well. Try adding these decorators(@sleep_and_retry and @limits) to the line above the `wrapped` function

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the solutions offered by others weren't satisfying your initial question, so I came up with a simple and synchronous solution for you, there is no need for fancy multithreading. This problem can be solved by using a lower-level library such as `socket` that comes built-in with python. The idea is sending the get request and not caring whether the other party returns a 200 or 400+, thus allowing us to truly fire and forget, not wasting any precious time, not awaiting anything. [Here is the full code demonstrating the usefulness and implementation](https://github.com/MovsisyanM/sandbox/tree/main/TrueFireAndForget)

and the general idea is doing

```
write_only_client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
write_only_client.connect((target_host, target_port))
write_only_client.send(request.encode())
write_only_client.close()
```

notice how we don't do any `write_only_client.recv` calls, which is exactly why we are able to do a true fire and forget.

P.S.
Although it is not practiced in my code example, it is best to keep the socket open and have it as a global variable to avoid it being garbage collected during a scope change, as closing the socket too soon might cause problems (it did cause problems when I closed an SSL connection to an API).

Comment: Hi, I followed your suggestion which makes the most sense in my use case. However, I have an SSL connection, and my request message is never received. I did not close the connection as you mentioned; anything else I might be missing? I would like to point out that my GET endpoint does have endlines (**\n**) in the endpoint as I am constructing the message on a parameter, something like: `/message?text="example \n\n example"`

Comment: Try sending multiple messages at once, does the problem persist then? The other messages can be jibberish

Comment: And if sending mutiple requests doesnt work either, make sure that the server expects what you are sending at the end of the request (LF for linux, CRLF for others)@ISimion

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit verbose, but you can use the standard library http.client.HTTPSConnection:

```
import http.client, json
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.now()
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("medium.com")

#not needed for this call, but you may need to send data on your calls
payload = json.dumps({"Some": [{"json": ["string"]}]})

#not needed for this call, but you may need to send headers on your calls
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

# add querystring params here if needed
urlPath = "/towards-data-science/current-time-python-4417c0f3bc4f"

# do the call
conn.request("GET", urlPath, payload, headers)
print('Needed time to do the call: ', datetime.now() - d)
d = datetime.now()

#You can remove code from this point on and call is still made
res = conn.getresponse()
print('Time getting response (could skip): ', datetime.now() - d)
d = datetime.now()

data = res.read()
print('Time to read: ', datetime.now() - d)
# print(data.decode("utf-8"))

>>> Needed time to do the call:  0:00:00.180057
>>> Time getting response (could skip):  0:00:00.646882
>>> Time to read:  0:00:00.001001
```

Good luck!