# Wait for db future to complete?

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, sanic

I have written a code for sanic application, rethinkdb is being used as a backend database. I want to wait for rethinkdb connection function to intialise before other functions as they have dependency on rethinkdb connection.

My rethinkdb connection initialization function is:

```
async def open_connections(app):
   logger.warning('opening database connection')
   r.set_loop_type('asyncio')
   connection= await r.connect(
       port=app.config.DATABASE["port"],
       host=app.config.DATABASE["ip"],
       db=app.config.DATABASE["dbname"],
       user=app.config.DATABASE["user"],
       password=app.config.DATABASE["password"])
   print (f"connection established {connection}")
   return connection
```

The call back function which will be executed after future gets resolved is

```
def db_callback(future):
        exc = future.exception()
        if exc:
            # Handle wonderful empty TimeoutError exception
            logger.error(f"From mnemonic api isnt working with error {exc}")
            sys.exit(1)

        result = future.result()
        return result
```

sanic app:

```
def main():
        app = Sanic(__name__)
        load_config(app)
        zmq = ZMQEventLoop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(zmq)
        server = app.create_server(
            host=app.config.HOST, port=app.config.PORT, debug=app.config.DEBUG, access_log=True)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        ##not wait for the server to strat, this will return a future object
        asyncio.ensure_future(server)

        ##not wait for the rethinkdb connection to initialize, this will return
        ##a future object
        future = asyncio.ensure_future(open_connections(app))
        result = future.add_done_callback(db_callback)
        logger.debug(result)

        future = asyncio.ensure_future(insert_mstr_account(app))
        future.add_done_callback(insert_mstr_acc_callback)


        future = asyncio.ensure_future(check_master_accounts(app))
        future.add_done_callback(callbk_check_master_accounts)

        signal(SIGINT, lambda s, f: loop.close())


        try:
            loop.run_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            close_connections(app)
            loop.stop()
```

When i start this app, the print statement in open_connections functions executes in the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
future = asyncio.ensure_future(open_connections(app))
result = future.add_done_callback(db_callback)
```

`ensure_future` schedules coroutines concurrently

`add_done_callback` does not wait for the completion of the future, instead it simply schedules a function call after the future is completed. You can see it [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/futures.py#L193)

So you should explicitly [await](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables) the `open_connections` future before performing other functions:

```
future = asyncio.ensure_future(open_connections(app))
future.add_done_callback(db_callback)
result = await future
```

**EDITED: the answer above applies only to coroutine**

In this case we want to wait for the completion of future in the function body. To do it we should use `loop.run_until_complete`

```
def main():
    ...
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(open_connections(app))
    future.add_done_callback(db_callback)
    result = loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Comment: Nothing changed, the rethinkdb initilisation still completes at the end.

Comment: I think the whole point of await is that it passes the control back to event loop.

Comment: Yes, it is, but it also suspends the execution of coroutine on awaitable object until it completes

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that we are calling `open connections` not in a coroutine. I am going to edit my answer

Comment: @sauravverma I have supplemented the answer

Comment: loop.run_until_complete(future), dont you think it will stop the loop after completion of coroutine?

Comment: No, I have made an [example](https://repl.it/repls/BlindDramaticPlans) on the playground, that should approve my point